# Spring JPA | Duplicate entry "username" for key "..." when adding to a ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently trying to update a system which has users and user profile information working.

The idea is to keep a few versions of the profile information in certain conditions and as such **I intended to switch the profile information from being identified by the user id (that is the username) to be identified by a sequentially generated id (to keep track of the order).**

Previously the relationship was a simple OneToOne and now I wanted to do switch it to a OneToMany as I had done before for other cases.

Problem is the error I mentioned above **whenever trying to add new profile information to the database**:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: (conn=48) Duplicate entry 'usernameInQuestion' for key 'UK_141232asdas78k552'
```

The profile information class was previously this:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@MapsId
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")
private User user;
```

And was now changed to this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "username")
private User user;
```

While previously the User entity didn't reference the profile information and now:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
private String username;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<ProfileInformation> infos;
```

This occurs in the creation of profile information:

```
    ProfileInformation info = new ProfileInformation(infoDto, user);
    [...]
    info = profileInformationRepository.save(info);
```

I would need to still add the ProfileInformation to the User but the error occurs before that, I have tried that before so I expect it not to be the source of the problem, **I think it is in the actual saving of the Profile Information that it expects the username mapping to be unique... but why is that?**

I have no clue why doesn't this work as I have a similar relationship between the Profile Information and another entity (but in reverse, where there are many of those others entities for a single profile information) and it fully works.

PS - When talking to a friend I got reminded to add further information, I have already tried dropping the database and creating it again in fear that this was some weird limbo effect of a constraint from being previously OneToOne. This error occurs in a clean database.

Comment: Can you try to delete Cascade All and Fetch Eager ?

Comment: The Cascade didn't exist on the described problem, that was the previous code but I deleted fetch eager and same error :/